Is it possible to enable a proxy when tethering from iPhone to a Mac over USB?
When tethering over Wifi there's a Proxies tab available:

But no such tab is visible when tethering over a USB cable. Is there an alternative way to enable a SOCKS proxy when tethering over USB? Maybe some sort of a Terminal command?

Looks like the answer is no but happy to wait for someone to add an answer.
